# HTTPS not working; binding set, certificate installed

Tags: iis, iis-7, ssl, ssl-certificate, https

I've installed the certificate and set up the HTTPS bindings. However, when I load the site on HTTPS it does not load.

I've looked at all the settings but everything seems correct.

I've restarted the server numerous times. The certificate is stored on the local computer under Personal > Certificates. I have the private key for the certificate. The port (443) is open.

If I try `https://localhost` on the server, the site loads, but with a domain error (i.e., it's `localhost` and not `example.net`). But `https://example.net` doesn't load.

I really don't know why the HTTPS URL isn't loading.

Comment: What error do you get at https://thedomain.com?  A timeout?  A cert error?  A 404?  You say port 443 is open.  Where is it open?

Comment: I get a "Server not found" error. Port 443 is open for TCP under Firewall->Incoming Connections.

Comment: If you do a netstat -an at a command prompt do you see a line for port 443 in the local address column?

Comment: It's listening on :443 ... but no ip address is specified (under the local address column).

Comment: In my case the server was on AWS and the inbound traffic was not allowed on port 443. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: @rksprst Have you got the correct answer to this question? I'm stucked on this issue

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting "Server Not Found", that means that the client could not find the responsible server to serve your request. In your case, that's a HTTPS-based application. You also said that HTTP works but HTTPS fails.

Verify the following:
Go to Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Firewall\Allowed Programs
Verify that you have "Secure World Wide Web Service (HTTPS)" and "Domain, Home/Work, and Public" both checked.

You also said that when you try `https://example.net` from the server itself, it fails. Try browsing the application from the server itself and run `netstat -ano` and check whether there is any activity happening on port 443.

Comment: It's listening on port 443.

Comment: Checking "Secure World Wide Web Service (HTTPS)" worked for me.

Comment: TCP     192.168.90.100:49706   40.90.19.152:443      ESTABLISHED     6284
  TCP    192.168.90.100:51655   111.22.29.254:443     TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.90.100:51662   205.15.16.42:80      ESTABLISHED     1192
  TCP    192.168.90.100:51663   152.19.19.11:443     TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.90.100:51666   111.22.29.254:443     ESTABLISHED     8364
  TCP    192.168.90.100:51667   151.253.18.12:443    SYN_SENT     //this server ip

Comment: after this there is no 443 port, and also site is not opened with https says This site can’t be reached

Comment: @alamnaryab Check the firewall may be not allowed 443 port or using any services..

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure that `example.net` actually points to the server's IP. You can do this either with an `nslookup` or just plain old `ping` the machine. This is your most likely cause.

Comment: It does point to the IP... the regular http domain works fine. It's only the https that is not working.

Comment: In that case, then you need to make sure that the port is actually open and accessible from the outside. Try:

`openssl s_client -connect host:port`

Comment: Tried it and got operation timed out for port 443... If I changed the port to 80 I get Connected)...

Comment: Then you better check your IIS configuration to ensure that it there is a binding for the SSL.

Comment: I had the same symptoms and it was a firewall blocking port 443

Comment: @Giovanni. Any particular reason to prefer `example.com` to `example.net`? I used `.net` for the question & both answers.

Comment: actually not :D

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the cause was that the firewall was blocking port 443, the same as a couple of other people in the comments of the other solutions.  I don't know how all firewall software works, but in Windows Azure, you have to explicitly add an Inbound Traffic rule to allow traffic on port 443.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and this problem occurred because of my router's port forwarding configuration. I configured my public IPs port forwarding on port 80, not 443. Thats why I can't access my site remotely using `HTTPS` protocol. I solved this problem by configuring my public IP port forwarding on port 443. Then it starts working. But first, make sure to check that port 443 is open and it is allowed on your firewall.